# How to update all the value from one column to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

**Table 1** -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 443 |
| 2 | 449 |
| 3 | 479 |

**Table 2** -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |

`Note - col1 is not a PK`

**expected Output** -

**Table 2** -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 443 |
| 2 | 449 |
| 3 | 479 |

This is my python code:

```
abc_df = pd.read_sql_query("UPDATE Table1 SET Table1_id = t2.col1 FROM Table1 t1
                INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col2", con=connection)
```

**But My Actual OUTPUT is** -

**Table 2** -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 443 |
| 2 | 443 |
| 3 | 443 |

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6) do **not** repeat the target table of the UPDATE in the FROM clause

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your UPDATE query -

```
UPDATE Table2 T2
   SET col2 = T1.col2
  FROM Table1 t1
 WHERE T1.col1 = T2.col1
```

Comment: In an update in Postgres, you omit the alias from the LValue of the update.  The target table is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

in your update query there is 2 part are wrong first one where set the table2 data, you used Table1_id = t2.col1 but you should used t2.col2 = t1.col2 and other wrong thing in join condition you used t1.col2 = t2.col2 but you should used t1.col1 = t2.col1

update your query as per following

```
Update Table2 T2 SET T2.col2 = T1.col2 FROM 
Table1 t1 WHERE T1.col1 = T2.col1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I will add to existing answers is in general updates can be expensive operations, so put in a check to be sure you NEED to update it before you do it.

```
update table1 t1
set col2 = t2.col2
from table2 t2
where
  t1.col1 = t2.col1 and
  t1.col2 is distinct from t2.col2   -- added this check
```

Because of MVCC, it will actually create a new record and create a dead space where the previous record was (until the next vacuum), so it makes senses on many levels to not update a record if all you are doing is replacing the value.

I realize in your example you were replacing all nulls, but in general this is just a good practice.